# GCM native permission prompt - can it be replaced or adjusted?

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, web-notifications

Does anyone know if the GCM native notification prompt you see on Browsers such as Chrome, can be replaced or adjusted in any way so that we show a more presentable popup instead?

Here is a native prompt example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot customize it.

The only option would be do draw your custom dialog with HTML / CSS, then when someone clicks subscribe display the default browser dialog: I've already seen it on some websites, but I strongly recommend against it (because of the bad UX it provides).

Comment: Yes, I agree. We will stick to the default behavior. Thanks for the confirmation.